# How are CS:GO eSport competitive leagues typically structured?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, competitive-gaming

I have a *fairly* firm grasp on how League of Legends eSport leagues work with the LCS, LPL, and OPL leagues culminating in a world championship. The Overwatch league is also quite similar. After recently attending the IEM Sydney event I'm not entirely clear on how CS:GO's eSports scene functions. Is there a common league, or is it more of an invitational circuit for players to grow their identity on an individual level?

Some guidance in this would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Something like [this](http://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/Majors)? Or what exactly are you looking for? Listing a complete tournament structure would be pretty broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LoL and OW leagues are built pretty much like hockey and basketball.

You have a regular season, that feeds into playoffs, that crown a champion. Then sometimes those champions will go into a tournament of champions (like MSI for LoL)

In CSGO, it works more like Tennis. You have a few leagues that run like LCS and OWL, where theres a season and then playoffs; but most events are a 1-2 weekend tournament. Teams are set into groups, and then it feeds in a playoff tree and then it crowns a champion; but when that event is over, nothing really carries into the next one. You get a prize purse; and that's pretty much it. You might be making a name for yourself to get directly invited to other events and dont have to go through qualifiers, but you dont get points on a ladder or anything.

So:

- LCS and OWL run like hockey, where teams are stuck in that league and won't be playing in other leagues with the same lineup (like if the Vegas Knights would be to play in the KHL, that would be weird.)
- CSGO (and afaik, DOTA) leagues run more like Tennis, where you have things like the Masters, Winbeldon and the Rogers Cup. All tournaments where about the same players will play, but they are at most loosely related to eachother.

For CSGO, you might want to take a look at Majors, the tournaments that are maybe twice a year and they are the big one, that no team in their right mind will sit out.

Answer (score 1):

Starting after the Boston major event in 2018, CSGO has majors, challengers stage, and minors. The top 8 teams from the last major are automatically invited to the next major. The bottom 8 teams from the last major drop to challenger status. The top two teams from minor events are also invited to the challenger stage. The challenger stage teams ultimately compete to see who will secure spots in the next major.

These events are hosted by various tournament organizers. Valve typical requests proposal from the usual organizers (ESL, MLG, FaceIt, ELeague, etc.) and selects one or more tournament operators to run these events.